# select multiple columns from another table where field contains array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two table

```
phi_ads {id,files}
phi_files {id,file}
```

The problem is `phi_ads` contains array for example (20,21) this numbers is id for `phi_files`

So I need to select all this files

I try this

```
select a.name,d.*,f.* from phi_ads d 
inner join phi_areas a on a.id = d.area 
inner join phi_files f on f.id = d.files 
where d.id=42
```

for note `phi_ads.files = "102,103"` so return only first file , but I need to return all file in `phi_files`

I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IN operator  , The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
  phi_ads.files In (102,103)
```

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)**

**Update**

```
   select a.name,d.*,f.* from phi_ads d 
   inner join phi_areas a on a.id = d.area 
   inner join phi_files f on FIND_IN_SET( f.id , d.files )
   where d.id=42
```

**Update 2**

```
   select a.name,d.*,GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) as name from phi_ads d 
   inner join phi_areas a on a.id = d.area 
   inner join phi_files f on FIND_IN_SET( f.id , d.files )
   where d.id=42
```

Comment: the files number change , so do i have to get number first !!

Comment: Yes, you can get that using query inside IN operator, or by using separate query as well.

Comment: i did it , select a.name,d.*,f.* from phi_ads d inner join phi_areas a on a.id = d.area inner join phi_files f on f.id = d.files where d.id=42 and f.id in (d.files)

Comment: Can you provide sample data in your tables ?

Comment: phi_ads 
{ 
id=1
files=20,21,22
}

phi_files {
id=20
file=testname1
} 
{
id=21
file=testname2
}
{
id=22
file=testname3
}

Comment: Ok, you want to join two table where one column have comma separated values. Right ?

Comment: i need to return all filename like , testname1,testname2,testname3

Comment: hmm , it is great , but i need it to return it in one result , is it possible !! , cuz i make json_encode one time

Comment: You are getting expected result in multiple rows and you want in single row. Correct ?

Comment: Correct pro , single row

Comment: Brother , i try to get limit 5 , the result only 5 image not all rows !!